# Dlib face recognition , detection from multiple images

Tags: c++, opencv, openframeworks, dlib

I want to create a face recognition app with openframeworks + dlib based on this example 
https://github.com/kashimAstro/ofFaceRecognition

This example recognize faces from a given image and rearrange them in clusters, i want to use this example in my app which supposed to track faces from a webcam ,save them in a folder . so i want to pass all those images inside a loop and arrange them in clusters ,

[image]

the ofFaceRecognition object can find faces in one image input, the question is how can i make it able to find faces from multiple images and the output would be clusters which contains faces from all images

```
ofFaceRecognition face_recognition;

ofImage img("test.jpg");
face_recognition.setup();
face_recognition.find(img);
face_recognition.cluster();
```

Comment: please check out its source code. ofFaceRecognition probably detects faces in an image and then run other base methods to cluster them. Maybe you can call those methods with your custom face list.

Comment: What do you use to clusterize detected faces? Do you extract any feature vectors (descriptors)?

Comment: @AlexeyAntonenko yes i did extract desctiptors and cluster them with chineese whisper algorithm,

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem to implement that. You might be want to:

1) find faces onto different images;

2) crop and align them;

3) run each crop through face descriptors extractor - obtain feature vectors;

4) clusterize them.

If you are not able to modify current code you'are using you may:

1) make steps 1 and 2 from above;

2) montage obtained crops - make a single image of faces (before montage maybe resize all faces to make them of the same size);

3) run obtained montage through your current code;

4) be happy.